# Opening an XML File and Returning the XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm working on my first Windows Forms tool for a project; this is my first time using C# extensively. Right now, my only objective is to be able to open an XML file and have the resulting XML in hand. I know this works, but I want to know if there's a better, or proper, way to do it.

There is also the issue that when I was first trying to load it, it didn't like the fact that I was using `if` statements, so the return class was giving me an error that said that not all of the branches returned a value.  So, I had to throw in a messy `else` statement that I don't like.

One thing to note; if the empty XML file is returned, I'll have a statement for handling the returned XML document to do nothing with it.

```
class LoadXML
{
    public XmlDocument LoadXML_Window(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //  The stream will hold the results of opening the XML
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialogXML = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialogXML.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFileDialogXML.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
        openFileDialogXML.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if(openFileDialogXML.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            myStream = openFileDialogXML.OpenFile();
            using (myStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    //  Successfully return the XML
                    XmlDocument parsedMyStream = new XmlDocument();
                    parsedMyStream.Load(myStream);
                    return parsedMyStream;
                }
                catch (XmlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The XML could not be read. " + ex);
                    XmlDocument emptyMyStream = new XmlDocument();
                    return emptyMyStream;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //  Return an empty XmlDocument if the open file window was closed
            XmlDocument emptyMyStream = new XmlDocument();
            return emptyMyStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would refactor your code:

- An event handler sholdn't return any values, it's better to save the result in a property or a field in this case.

> √ DO use a return type of void for event handlers.
>   An event handler can invoke multiple event handling methods, possibly on multiple objects. If event handling methods were allowed to return a value, there would be multiple return values for each event invocation.

[Event Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011(v=vs.110).aspx)

- You shouldn't do *too* much work inside an event handler, it's better to call a specialized method that can also be reused elsewhere later.
- `OpenFileDialog` needs to be disposed: see [Component.Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3cc9y48w(v=vs.110).aspx) which is one of the base class of this dialog.
- If you check the `if(!openFileDialogXML.ShowDialog())` for a `false` value and immediately return a default value you can reduce nesting.
- If possible it's better to name a class with a noun (e.g. `XmlLoader`) rather then like a method `LoadXml`.
- Now that the unnecessary nesting is removed you can remove the `Stream myStream = null;` and put it inside the `using`.
- The last step would be to replace the repeating creation of an empty `XmlDocument` by a method and call it where necessary. You might want to add some default elements later so now you can do it in only one place. If the `XmlDocument` is no longer empty you might rename the method to `CreateDefaultXmlDocument` but it's important that you do it only once. You could forget to adjust the other lines if your code repeates.

---

```
class XmlLoader
{
    public XmlDocument XmlDocument { get; private set; }

    private XmlDocument CreateEmptyXmlDocument()
    {
        //  Return an empty XmlDocument if the open file window was closed
        XmlDocument emptyMyStream = new XmlDocument();
        return emptyMyStream;
    }

    public XmlDocument OpenXml()
    {
        using(var openFileDialogXML = new OpenFileDialog())
        {       
            openFileDialogXML.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            openFileDialogXML.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
            openFileDialogXML.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if(!openFileDialogXML.ShowDialog())
            {
               return CreateEmptyXmlDocument();
            }

            //  The stream will hold the results of opening the XML
            using (var myStream = openFileDialogXML.OpenFile())
            {
                try
                {
                    //  Successfully return the XML
                    XmlDocument parsedMyStream = new XmlDocument();
                    parsedMyStream.Load(myStream);
                    return parsedMyStream;
                }
                catch (XmlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The XML could not be read. " + ex);
                    return CreateEmptyXmlDocument();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void LoadXML_Window(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument = OpenXml();
    }
}
```